# How to use Ideal 92-650 F connectors on RG-6 quad shield cable?

Tags: cabling

I bought a 50 pack of [Ideal 92-650 compression F connectors](http://www.idealindustries.ca/products/datacomm/connectors/f-series_comp_connectors.php). They're advertised to work on RG-6 and RG-6 Quad Shield cable. However, as I and other reviewers found, it's very difficult to push these connectors onto quad shield cable (normal RG-6 and tri-shield cable is OK).

When I do get them on, sometimes I've crumpled the foil shield in the process. Others have had problems with this as well. Does anyone have any tips for working with this connector or others that are too tight for RG-6Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to be clear you want to strip and fold back correctly.  Regular RG6 has these layers from the inside out:

```
center conductor 
dielectric 
foam 
foil 
braid 
jacket
```

Quad shield RG6 has an additional foil and an additional braid, so it's like this from the inside out:

```
center conductor 
dielectric 
foam 
inner foil 
inner braid 
outer foil 
outer braid 
jacket
```

So there's more material to fold back, and if it doesn't get folded back out of the way, you're going to get hung up inserting the connector.

When you strip the cable, you want to strip back 1/4" from the tip all the way to the center conductor, and another 1/4" of the jacket.  Then you fold back the outer braid, *tear off the outer foil*, fold back the inner braid, leave the inner foil on the dielectric.

If you fold everything back, and nothing gets tangled while inserting the connector, it should go in just a little tighter than regular RG6.

Comment: I wasn't tearing off the outer foil. I followed your instructions and the connectors work great. Thanks!